# Xamarin:Render pdf by MuPDF in Xamarin android

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android, mupdf

I want to use **MuPDF** reader for my **Xamarin Android** project .

In all pdf reader i found this **free PDF plugin** that has ported from **java** to **xamarin** . When i compile the project in viusal studio 2015(compiled with 23 api) and run it on emulator , it stops working .

Actually at first i rendered pdf with MuPDF without any problem, but after one day . i can't run it on emulator(or android device).

You can download or see  my project [here](https://github.com/LittleKing2020/XamarinMuPDF) .

Main site : [www.mupdf.com](http://www.mupdf.com/)

Followed instruction for this project : [xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9643/rendering-a-pdf-page-in-a-view)

Comment: How does it "stop working"? Does it crash? Does it just render a blank page? If you set a breakpoint on various parts of mupdf are they actually getting called? Are there any logging/debug messages being printed?

Comment: when i compile it , i didn't face any error . but when i open my app it stops working!

Comment: I added 4 activity for menu paging , does it cause the problem?

Comment: You still need to clarify what "stops working" means - what *exactly* happens - it locks up/stops responding, or the OS shows a dialogue to says the app has stopped working, etc etc. You didn't answer my question about debug/console output. If you remove the '4 activity for menu paging' (I have no idea what that is) does it work okay?

Comment: Android 4.4 OS shows app has stopped working, i removed 4 activity, but still stopped working in emulator . And in my android device working properly.What should i do?

Comment: You should look at the debug/console output from the app.

Comment: I didn't understand anything from "debug/console output " , but when i get the last version of MuPDF by nuget.org it worked correctly on both emulator and real device .

Comment: Thank you @JosephH

Answer (score 0):

At last i add MuPDF ported library from nuget.org
Just run following command in the Package Manager Console(the latest update).

```
Install-Package Askaiser.Android.MuPDF
```

that works correctly for **Xamarin** .